# Do I need to cast something?

Tags: java, json

So I have this call in a class

```
ord.ordenaMergeSort(json);
```

The json makes references to objects I construct from reading a json file:

```
public class Censo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException {
        JSONObject obj;    
        String fileName = "business10k.json";
        // This will reference one line at a time
        String line = null;
        Business[] json = new Business[10000];
      try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
                int i = 0;
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null && i < 500) {
                    obj = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(line);
                    json[i] = new Business(obj);
                    i++;
                }
                // Always close files.
                bufferedReader.close();         
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");                
            }
            catch(IOException ex) { 
                System.out.println("Error reading file '" + fileName + "'");
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }            
            ord.ordenaMergeSort(json);
```

then I proceed to open the file and create the objects.

When I try to call the method, there's an error that says "no suitable method found for ordenaMergeSort(Business[]) method ord.#1 ordenaMergeSort(T#1) is not applicable (interface variable T#1 has incompatible bounds upper bounds ComparableT#1 lower bounds Business)" and this is the method I'm trying to use:

```
public class ord {
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void ordenaSelectSort(T[] arr){
        //T[]arr =(T[])(ar);
        int pos, sum = 0;
        T temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            pos = i;
            sum++;
            for (int j = i; j < arr.length; j++){
                sum++;
                if(arr[j].compareTo(arr[pos]) < 0){
                    pos = j;
                }//if                
            }//for
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[pos];
            arr[pos] = temp;
        }//for
        System.out.println("El metodo selectSort reviso " + sum + "datos con una entrada de tamanio " + arr.length);
    }//method
}//class
```

This is the Business class:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Business {
    private String name;
    private JSONObject obj;

    public Business(JSONObject obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
        this.name = obj.get("name").toString();
    }

    public int compareTo(Business c){
        return this.name.compareTo(c.getName());
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setBussines_id(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

I'm not sure if I need to change or cast something?

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace for the exception you’re getting, is it for when you call this method or from within it?

Comment: Here it is: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: Tareas.ord.ordenaMergeSort
 at Tareas.Censo.main(Censo.java:42)` and I get the exception when I call this method

Comment: What type is `json`? How are you _actually_ calling this class? This is a static method, so you'd typically call it with `ClassName.ordenaSelectSort(someArray)`, but you seem to be using an instance to call it. You should add more code.

Comment: The ClassName where the method can be found is ord, that's why I use ord.ordenaSelectSort

Answer (score 0):

First, just a style note. `ord` is a bad class name. Convention is that class names start with a capital letter, which is why I was confused in your previous, u nedited question. I'd also choose a more descriptive name, since it's unclear what `ord` is. (Though this could be just a language difference and `Ord` is a fine class name.)

Your `Business` class is simply defined as

```
public class Business
```

Your method that accepts a generic is defined as

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void ordenaSelectSort(T[] arr)
```

The key part: `T extends Comparable<T>`

This means that the method will only accept classes that extend (or implement in this case) `Comparable`, which your `Business` class does not.

The solution is to implement `Comparable`

```
public class Business implements Comparable<Business>
```

Comment: Missed that, they sure did! Edited

Comment: OP must be thinking that creating a `compareTo` method within the `Business` class automatically makes it a `Comparable` or something.